# ETL jobs are failing due to excessive amount of data in big query

Tags: google-bigquery

We are maintaining transaction and historical tables in big query.
If today transaction table have 100 records, the same 100 records would be reflected in history as well. the transaction table is WRITE_TRUNCATE and historical table contains appended data of every day snapshot.
The historical table is now reached to 1 billion. i am pulling the data based on transnational and historical tables into another table by using ETL job. The ETL job is failing while pulling data from historical table.
Is there any solution for this, i dont want to modify the ETL job.

Comment: Can you share more details around your "ETL" job? Is that SQL? Is it Dataflow? There's not a lot of information to work with here..

Comment: The ETL job will take the query that we provided and it will truncate the transaction table, the truncated table data is moved to historical table. There are so many duplicates are there in the history table. when i am trying to pull the data from both history and transactional table by using left join into another table by using same ETL job then job is failing